# Missing space between consecutive @

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex

I noticed today, while experimenting with TeX, a missing space between consecutive @'s :

```
@ @ @ @
\bye
```

The dvi output, after interpretation by the TeX program (on the command line on linux) shows :
@ @@ @
(there is a missing space between the second and the third @). I observed the same output with pdfTeX but not with latex.
Why is that so?

Comment: I see four equally spaced `@` characters after compiling with `pdfTeX`

Comment: Checked with `tex` and `dvi2tty`: Four equally spaced `@` characters!

Comment: Add the tracing lines that I show in my answer, and then post the log you get from tex, adding to your question in a code section.

Comment: Ok, problem solved, I was sometimes keeping the right alt-key pushed while pressing space, which resulted on an unknown charcacter... Sorry and thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to erroneous input (unbreakable space and not space)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

processed with (pdf)tex the log shows four `@` with three equal word spaces

```
..\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 408.6438fil
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x20.0
...\tenrm @
...\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
...\tenrm @
...\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
...\tenrm @
...\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
...\tenrm @
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
```

Tracing enabled via:

```
\tracingoutput=1
\showboxbreadth=10
@ @ @ @
\bye
```

Comment: What do you see with tex ?

Comment: @Villetaneuse identical log

Comment: As I said, in the previous comments, this was due to TeX and pdfTeX making a difference between `space` and `right-Alt + space`. Sorry for the inconvenience.