# "show" family debugging commands

Tags: debugging

As discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60491/latex-tracing-commands-list), there are many commands which can be used to "debug" (La)TeX composing process.

I also know that sometimes the `\show` command can be used to show the macro definitions.

Nevertheless I know that there are some debug/tracing commands which start with show, for example `\showboxbreadth=xx` as one can see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/364937/89949).

Is there any list of such commands and their doings?

Comment: The TeXBook lists all the ones in TeX, and etex (`texdoc etex`) adds a few more. there are also some convenience latex macros starting with show such as `\showoutput` (or rather etex adds more `\tracing...` commands)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The book [`TeX By Topic`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf) by Victor Eijkhout describes some `\show...` macros.

In the following overview `X` means some integer value and Y and 8-bit number, `\Z` is short for some 'internal quantity' such as a `count`, `dimen`, `\skip` or `token` register, `W` is a word or space separated list of words.

- `\show` is primitive command and shows the meaning of a token, i.e. what `\meaning\foo` does within the document.
- `\showboxdepth=X` has the value of the deepest level of box nesting, defaulting to `X=3` in plain `TeX`
- `\showboxbreadth=X` has the maximum number of items shown per level 
  This has a plain `TeX` default of `X=5`
- `\showlists` is a primitive and writes the content of partial box lists in all of the 4 non-math TeX modes (i.e. horizontal/vertical and the restricted versions)
- `\showthe\Y` prints the content of a `\Y` quantity as in the document with `\the`, `\the\footoks`
- `\showhyphens{W}` displays the hyphenation of W on the terminal/log according to the hyphenation rules.

Now, the `eTeX` standard (which is a standard by now as of writing this in April 2017) adds some more `\show...` tools

- `\showifs` (activated with `\tracingifs=1`)
- `\showgroups` (`\tracinggroups=1`)
- `\showtokens` for token lists and content, that is not possible to show with `\show` or `\showthe`.

These three `eTeX` additions are mode-independent.

LaTeX adds some wrapper macros, such as

- `\showoutput`
- `\showoverfull`
- `\showhyphens` (being redefined)

and sets initially `\showboxbreadth=-1` and `\showboxdepth=-1` as well.

Here's a sample LaTeX document for the plain TeX `\show...` entities.

```
\documentclass{article}


\newbox\foobox

\setbox\foobox=\hbox{A nice text}


\newcount\foocnt
\foocnt=17


\newtoks\footok
\footok={Gandalf The Grey}

\tracingoutput=1
\tracingonline=1

\begin{document}
\showboxbreadth=10 
\showboxdepth=2
\scrollmode
\showbox\foobox

\showthe\footok

\showthe\foocnt

% Show lists 
a\hfil\break b\par
c\hfill\break d
\hbox{e\vbox{f\showlists}}

\end{document}
```

The output is both on console as in the `.log` file (here I cut the header and the bottom statistics to provide the `\show...` related output only):

```
> \box26=
\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x48.88896
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 A
.\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66498 minus 1.11221
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 n
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 i
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 c
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
.\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 t
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 x
.etc.

! OK.
l.23 \showbox\foobox


> Gandalf The Grey.
l.25 \showthe\footok


> 17.
l.27 \showthe\foocnt



### horizontal mode entered at line 32
\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 f
spacefactor 1000
### internal vertical mode entered at line 32
prevdepth ignored
### restricted horizontal mode entered at line 32
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
spacefactor 1000
### horizontal mode entered at line 31
\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 c
\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fill
\penalty -10000
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 d
\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
spacefactor 1000
### vertical mode entered at line 0
### current page:
\write-{}
\glue(\topskip) 5.69446
\hbox(4.30554+0.0)x345.0, glue set 324.99998fil
.\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 a
.\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.\penalty -10000
.\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
\penalty 300
\glue(\baselineskip) 5.05556
\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x345.0, glue set 339.44443fil
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 b
.\penalty 10000
.\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
total height 22.0 plus 1.0
 goal height 550.0
prevdepth 0.0

! OK.
l.32 \hbox{e\vbox{f\showlists
                             }}


Overfull \hbox (12.22223pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 31--33
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 d [] 

\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x345.0, glue set - 1.0
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 d
.\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
.\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x349.44444
..\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
..\vbox(6.94444+0.0)x345.0 []
.\penalty 10000
.\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.\glue(\rightskip) 0.0


Completed box being shipped out [1]
\vbox(633.0+0.0)x407.0
.\glue 16.0
.\vbox(617.0+0.0)x345.0, shifted 62.0
..\vbox(12.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 12.0fil []
..\glue 25.0
..\glue(\lineskip) 0.0
..\vbox(550.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 503.94617fil []
..\glue(\baselineskip) 23.55556
..\hbox(6.44444+0.0)x345.0, glue set 170.0fil []
```

Comment: `\tracingoutput=1` is not needed for `\show...` to have effect; `\tracingonline=1` is needed for `\showbox` to list the box's contents on the terminal, in addition to the log file. The macro `\showhyphens` is defined also in plain TeX. Being picky, but… +1 anyway. `;-)`